# Bind a URL from a Website to another Website Controller with IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, redirect

I have two MVC websites:

- `www.website1.com/Mobile`
- `www.website2.com`

I need to create a URL *www.website2.com/mobile* that points to *www.website1.com/Mobile* **without any redirect**, I have to stay in the URL *www.website2.com/Mobile* and open the content of *www.website1.com/Mobile* Controller/View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a few ways to do this:

1. iFrame. You could make a page under `www.website2.com/mobile` that points to `www.website1.com/Mobile` but the address bar would remain the same. [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) has some basics where I've also used this as a way to generate a page within a page concept.
2. Reverse Proxy. Nginx could be used to make the site under `www.website2.com/Mobile` go to `www.website1.com/Mobile` as one software package that could be used. [Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) would have more specific details though I have used this at times in the past.

From the second link as an example:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

In your case, you'd likely want to do something like this:

```
location /Mobile {
    proxy_pass http://www.website1.com/Mobile/;
}
```

Course one does have to ensure that Nginx is configured properly as it is kind replacing your initial web server here. The idea would be that Nginx does the redirecting and stuff behind the scenes through its proxying stuff that the user never notices.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am not familiar with Nginx, any example that you can share? Is it compatible with IIS?

Comment: Hi, I have check your answer has correct but I still would like to know how can I use your solution in IIS7.5. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick you can use ARR extension for IIS to configure IIS as reverse proxy http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `iframe` inside *www.website2.com/Mobile*'s view like the following to get the content from another domain without redirection:

```
<iframe src="http://website1.com/Mobile" width = "100%" 
    height="1000" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

I exhort you to return `PartialView` for *www.website1.com/Mobile* controller action to have a more stylish page on the website2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I have set JB's answer has correct because he answered right after I created it.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML5 you can use "object":

```
    <div id="MainPage" >
       <object type="text/html" data="second site URL" style="width: 100%; height: 128px;">
       </object>
     </div>
```